# How can I indicate that I am a "cooperative" questioner?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I pretty regularly scan my asked questions and upvote good answers.  I figure if somebody's going to take the trouble to answer one of my questions, it's the least I can do.

I'd like to be able to indicate this somehow: it's worthwhile answering my questions, coz I'll show my appreciation by upvoting your good answers.

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should suggest some sort of badge for this. I suggested one for commenting edits, and Jeff seemed to think it was a good idea.  I think what you are asking for would be really good if it were some kind of public badge, the way moderator is.

I've created a request [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20081026075832/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/pages/general/suggestions/17688?):

> I think ideally we would have two badges here. The first badge would be for selecting an "accepted answer" for, say, 50% of questions asked. The second would be for upvoting at least, say, 15% of answers to your questions (maybe more?).
>
> Both of these badges would be best if they were volatile badges, in that they would come and go based on continued good behavior on the part of the user. e.g., If your "selected answer" ratio falls below 50%, you lose the badge.

Comment: Most people answering a question do not go looking if you have a specific badge in order to determine whether or not they should answer.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there probably isn't a way - but I agree there should be.

Perhaps a series of badges could be established that encourage people to do as you, and serve to show who else is doing it too.

Alternatively I suppose you could put something in your gravatar image that indicates it.

Comment: I don't think it should be in the gravatar image. I agree with the rest of the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

I agree. There should be some ort of badge, or series of badges for this. It really helps the system when people are willing to go back and look through their answers and give something back to the people answering them.

There would need to be some safety measures though as some people will do it just to get the badge and abuse it some, although I guess that is true of most of the bronze badges.

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Just do what you're already doing. People will notice their rep has gone up next time they log in, view their profile, and see more votes.

They can't tell that the votes came from *you* AFAIK, but I don't think that's a problem.

Answer (score -9):

I have stated in [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/527/ggasp") that I vote up every answer my questions get.

Comment: I'm not going to upvote a wrong answer, no matter what.